# ionic ionchange and ngOnit same method when i enter page twice ,method will call three times, how can i avoid it?

Tags: angular, ionic4

my code html is

```
 <ion-col>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" [(ngModel)]="startDate" cancelText="取消" doneText="完成"
                      (ionChange)="getOrder()"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button color="dark" disabled size="small" shape="clear">
          ~
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" [(ngModel)]="endDate" cancelText="取消" doneText="完成"
                      (ionChange)="getOrder()"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-col>
```

and my ts is

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrder();
  }
  getOrder(){

    ....
  }
```

first enter page getOrder method call once, but when i enter page again . it call three times how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue ; ionChange cause the problem,
i have replace it to ngModelChange